# How to add text to svg circle in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, d3-force-directed

I have the following code and I would like to add text in the circles. How could I make it possible; I have looked at these possible duplicates

[Insert text inside Circle in D3 chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189740/insert-text-inside-circle-in-d3-chart)

```
 const link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#999")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", d => Math.sqrt(d.value));

// link.append("title").text(d => d.value);

const node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", "#fff")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.group))
    .call(drag(simulation));

node.append("title").text(d => "Node: " + d.id);

function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

    node
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous ways to add text labels to circles. In your code, you've added `title` elements to the circles, which usually show up as tooltips when you hover over the element. Unlike `title` elements, text elements cannot be added as children of the `circle` elements. One common way to handle them is to use `g` elements to group together the `circle` and the related `text`, so that you can then perform any transformations (or removals, etc.) on the `g` instead of having to apply them separately to `text` and `circle`.

To convert your code sample, first, I've altered the `selectAll` / `enter` code to act on `g` elements instead of circles:

```
const node = svg
  [...]
  .selectAll('.circle')
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append('g')  // for each item in nodes, add <g class='circle'>
  .classed('circle', true)
```

You can then append the `circle` and `text` elements to `node`:

```
node
  .append("circle")
  .attr('r', 5)

node
  .append("text")
  .text(d => "Node: " + d.id)
```

See the code snippet for a full example.

```js
var nodes = [{
  "x": 80,
  "y": 60,
  id: 'foo'
}, {
  "x": 20,
  "y": 70,
  id: 'bar'
}, {
  "x": 40,
  "y": 40,
  id: 'baz'
}, {
  "x": 50,
  "y": 90,
  id: 'bop'
}];
const svg = d3.select('svg')

const node = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .selectAll(".circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('circle', true)
  .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')');

node
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", 'deepskyblue')
//    .call(drag(simulation));

node
  .append("text")
  .classed('circleText', true)
  .attr('dy', '0.35em')
  .attr('dx', 5)
  .text(d => "Node: " + d.id);
```

```css
svg .circleText {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  fill: black;
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="200"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I understood your code. I did what you mentioned but my nodes are still overlapping. Is my code sufficient to diagnose this problem? I have updated my question.

Comment: That's a different issue so you should revert this question to its original state and create a new question about it. It'd also be helpful if you add your data to the Q in case it is a related to the dataset.

Comment: I have added the new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52804351/force-directed-graphs-nodes-stick-to-the-center

Comment: this is what I want as a new d3 builder, thanks